# Typescript - Communicate between unrelated controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angularjs-scope, rootscope

In a view that is displayed on the right side of my page I display a list of items. When pressing on a button on the upper part of the page a new pop up window with a different controller is created, in which those list items can be changed - be deleted added or modified.

In what way should I let the right side of my page know that a change in this list of items has just happend?

As for now I know of two ways:

1. Have the updating controller broadcast an event on $rootScope, although I hate the fact that it will go down through all the scopes.
2. My ng-repeat on the effected list could look like this:
   ng-repeat="item in vm.ItemsService.Items"
   And have both the controllers binded to a list of items present on a singleton service. However, I hate the fact of having my data stored in a signleton service like this. Feels right to me that a service should be stateless and have only logical functions.

Are there any different options?
What is the way to go?

Comment: Definitely a service - use the factory pattern with a getter/setter. I'm not sure why it doesn't "feel right" to you, but that is a very common design pattern to share data between controllers in Angular.

Comment: Because isn't it bad practice that this data ia saved in a singleton service and therefore lives for the lifetime of the application? And if later this list of items could be modified in a different controller as well it could concurrency issues couldn't it? (I'm used to writting server side code)

Comment: As for first approach - you can use `$rootScope.$emit` instead of `$broadcast`. Another controller should subscribe to event on `$rootScope` (don't forget to unsubscribe). This way it will **not** go down through all the scopes.

Comment: Ok but for general understanding, why not keep all data in application lifetime services, that will reduce my requests to the server whenever creating controllers? Should I keep all the data in those services than?